# increase padding between panel icons in xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu

I'm trying to increase the distance between the icons in the right side of the panel in xubuntu 16.04.Is there a way of doing it through the gtk theme , lets say modifying it,so the padding between the icons (bluetooth, network, sound, date etc.) gets bigger?
thanks in advance.

Comment: By padding to you mean the separator(s)?

Comment: No, I mean the "gap" between the icons. I have the keyboard layout indicator, bluetooth indicator, the wifi  indicator, sound , email, date  and time and  action button.The bluetooth, wifi and sound is a group and the gap between them is fixed .Using the separators does not changing this gap.

Comment: I found this article https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6844 but i dont know how to build or compile and install systray-box.c file.